# Call function through livewire with the value of a custom data-attribute as a parameter

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a select input which, using livewire, calls a function whenever the selection changes. According to the [documentation](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/actions#magic-actions) you can use `$event.target.value` to get to the selected value, however I want to send a different attribute value (myvalue) to my function.

```
<!-- this doesnt work -->

<select wire:onchange="myfunction($event.target.dataset.myvalue)">
    <option value="1" data-myvalue="12345">
</select>
```

I got it working using Alpine.js but it seems odd that I need another framework to do so.

```
<!-- this does work, but requires alpine.js -->

<select x-data='{}' @change="$wire.call('myfunction',$el.options[$el.selectedIndex].dataset.myvalue)">
    <option value="1" data-myvalue="12345">
</select>
```

Is there a pure livewire solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Your first code snippet is practically there already. The documentation you linked, in which `$event` is described, even shows why your code snippet doesn't work:

Your code uses `wire:onchange`, but Livewire checks for `wire:change`.

With your example though, you could also use `wire:model="foo"` and hook into the `updatedFoo($newValue)` function.

See the [lifecycle hooks doc](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks)